# How do I set environment variables in Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

In Capistrano 2, you could do something like this:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => '$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin'
}
```

Is there an equivalent in cap 3?

Comment: "'PATH' => 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin'"  should be "'PATH' => '$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin'", right?

Comment: Good point, I updated the example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use:

```
set :default_env, {
  'PATH' => 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin'
}
```

as of at least [capistrano 3.1](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/f7c49872ac4e9874ce037c6d058f6d69425adafa/lib/capistrano/templates/deploy.rb.erb#L31)

Comment: Where do these get saved on the server?

Comment: @RichPeck I am actually unsure about this, and from looking around a little, I don't see where they are saved.

Comment: I think they're set as `SHELL` variables - which means they exist for the period of the session

Comment: @MikeH-R are you missing a comma? Shouldn't it be `set :default_env, {
  'PATH' => 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin'
}`

Comment: Should be 'PATH' => 'new_path:$PATH', i.e. do not include PATH=... in the right-hand part

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late but...

Capistrano 3 uses a specia syntax for environment

```
on roles :app do
  with some_env: "foobar" do
    ...
  end
end
```

In the above example, within the with/end block capistrano sets the environment variable SOME_ENV to "foobar"

see https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#users-working-directories-environment-variables-and-umask